# Attempting to convert wp-login.php redirect form apache to nginx

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect, nginx

I'm moving my server from apache to nginx. Currently in place I have an apache redirect to ward off bots seeking out wp-login.php.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^login/?$ $1wp-login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^resetpass/?$ $1wp-login.php?action=resetpass [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^register/?$ $1wp-login.php?action=register [QSA,L]
```

With my current limited understanding of nginx I've converted it to:

```
location /login {
rewrite ^/login/?$ /$1wp-login.php break;
}
location /resetpass {
rewrite ^/resetpass/?$ /$1wp-login.php?action=resetpass break;
}
location /register {
rewrite ^/register/?$ /$1wp-login.php?action=register break;
}
```

What I'd like to happen is if someone goes to wp-login.php they get a 404 page and if they go to /login/ they get the login page.

Currently, with the new nginx setting on my test server if someone goes to /login/ the file wp-login.php is downloaded.

Ideas why as to this might happen and how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I see you've solved it with some plugin, but you simply forgot the basics: you haven't configured your upstream for php files. Once you do that, this will work just fine. If you are convinced you have handed off php files to php-fpm, then edit your question with that part of the config.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll look into that. Thank you. After contemplation, the solution I was looking for really did require a plugin. However, I'm interested in figuring out what I was doing wrong. I'll look into upstream config. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution at the bottom of [this page](http://centminmod.com/nginx_configure_wordpress.html).

I am now using [Rename wp-login.php](http://wordpress.org/plugins/rename-wp-login/) with the following code in my nginx conf file:

```
location = /renamedloginurl/ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that going to pass the content to `index.php` and not `wp-login.php`?

Comment: nm, that makes sense if you are using a plugin